# Curl 400 error when call yahoo search result

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I am scraping yahoo search results  
.i got yahoo search form action  
[yahoo search result](http://search.yahoo.com/search?toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&.tsrc=yfp-t-&p=bollywood%20songs)

but when i call using curl its give 400 error why?  
but this url in web browser working fine. please help me.

Comment: 400 is a bad request.Post your cURL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be messing the headers on **`CURLOPT_HEADER`**. This will help

```
 <?php
  $url='http://search.yahoo.com/search?toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&.tsrc=yfp-t-&p=bollywood%20songs';
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  $ret = curl_exec($curl);
  echo $ret;
```